# Run as java application option disabled in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I had started working on Eclipse IDe 3.6. I had written a normal java program and when I tried running it(right click/run), am unable to find the '**run as java application**' option. What am I missing here(Setting up the run configuration ?). Please help !!

Comment: Do you have a static main void defined somewhere?

Comment: Are you in the java perspective? The context menus are, well, contexual. Is  `Run as java application` available in the run menu?

Comment: Am in Java perspective. Am having a static void main(String p[]), and  Run as java application is still disabled/not available.

Comment: Do your project have the Java Nature's set?

Comment: The .project file shows both <buildspec> and <natures>

Comment: If you restart the eclipse or change the workspace, that solution worked for me.

Comment: While creating a new class always check the " public static void main(String[] args)" check box.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try and add a new run configuration: Run -> Run Configurations ... -> Select "Java Appliction" and click "New".

Alternatively use the shortcut: place the cursor in the class, then press  `Alt + Shift + X` to open up a context menu, then press `J`.

Comment: This has worked. Am still wondering why am unable to see 'Run as/ Java application' on the right click

Comment: Doesn't work. I am not getting either method to get a "Run as Java Application". I had just created a JavaClass.java on disk and wrote a main method in it with a sysout statement to test. I didn't and don't intend to write/setup a full fledged Java project with package name and all in which case "Run as java app" simply comes. I want to run one independent Java class with a main method.

Comment: @AnujBalan, have you found a solution to this problem other than Thomas's solution?  Because, as you said, this works, but one still cannot use the right click, there is no Run as Java Application.

Comment: @aez I just re-checked this in Eclipse 4.3 and if there is a correct main method, "Run as Java Application" is available in the context menu.

Answer (score 42):

Had the same problem.
I apparently wrote the Main wrong:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

I missed the `[]` and that was the whole problem.

Check and recheck the Main function!

Comment: ***facepalms***

Comment: Also make sure the class name should be same as java file name to enable "Run as java Application"

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem.  For me, the reason turned out to be that I had a mismatch in the name of the class and the name of the file.  I declared class "GenSig" in a file called "SignatureTester.java".

I changed the name of the class to "SignatureTester", and the "Run as Java Application" option showed up immediately.

Comment: thanks it shows my error

Answer (score 3):

`Run As > Java Application` wont show up if the class that you want to run does not contain the `main` method. Make sure that the class you trying to run has `main` defined in it.

Comment: It did have. It is just that it didn't show the run as app.

Comment: While creating a new class always check the " public static void main(String[] args)" check box.

Comment: I had typo "Main" instead of "main"

Comment: Class has to be public to see ' Run As-> Java Application' option